# Making An Animation in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ios

i have an question that how we can make the animation in iphone app like the notes app deletion animation.

if possible then please provide me the code for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The note app use a UITableView. So if you use a UITableView too, you can use the following method :

```
NSArray *indexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPathToDelete];
[myTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

Hope it will help.

PS : More information on apple documentation : [UITableView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteRowsAtIndexPaths%3awithRowAnimation%3a)